# Does "xcode 15 not reflecting fonts used in storyboard" have enough details?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I am looking for understanding on what I missed here; I'm not trying to argue the system.

I recently failed a [first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review) audit for this: [Xcode 15 not reflecting fonts used in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138588/xcode-15-not-reflecting-fonts-used-in-storyboard)

I tried to flag it as needing more details or clarity, but apparently it's fine. Can someone in the iOS specialty give me some insight, maybe?

Comment: This seems like a case where it _looks_ like a vague question visually (no reprex), but I guess it's fine if you're familiar with the domain. If you're in doubt and you're not familiar with the subject, skip it. I may have failed this audit too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flip it on its head.

What *more* could the OP have added to make it so that there's enough detail?

From what I read:

- The OP states their tool and its version
- What they're doing with the tool
- What behavior they observed and how it's undesirable

Like, what else do you need here?  This feels like it's enough for an expert in Xcode to be able to answer.